# Passing dates from SQL server to jQuery Calendar using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am following a jQuery calendar example as shown below and trying to load the dates from my SQL database instead of the sample hardcoded values, not sure what's the best approach but I am using Ajax post to my web method and fetch the data. The data from the database will be loaded into a datatable but the problem is I am not sure what format should the data from my SQL be stored such that when I retrieve it and return it to my Ajax call, it can replace "new Date(y, m, 2)".

Please kindly assist. Thanks.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var sDate;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/WebServices/Services.asmx/GetString",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) { sDate = result.d; }
        });
        alert(sDate);

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 2), // Hardcoded date
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });
    });

</script>

      [WebMethod]
        public string GetString()
        { // Dump data from SQL database into DataTable
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);
            return table;
        }
```

Comment: Which database/server side language are you using? There are timestamp and datetime datatype in database that can be used to save date. Your server side language should parse date to match your requirements on frontend.

Comment: You know, `sDate` is not available until the ajax callback is made, so the alert will always be empty in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor can take many different parameters. Milliseconds is pretty stable, but if your DB stores Unix timestamp, remember to convert it to milliseconds before you call the Date constructor (multiply it with 1000).

A sidenote: your code will not work as intended, because `sDate` is not available until the ajax callback is complete. You need to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WebServices/Services.asmx/GetString",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: onSuccess
});

function onSuccess(result) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date( result.d*1000 ), // assuming UNIX time
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });
}
```